# Bejeweled Blitz Hypercube Matching

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

On the Bejewled Blitz gameplay page (somewhere, by PopCap), it says something special happens when you match two HyperCubes.

I've had two hypercubes on the screen before (not adjacent), and matching one still leaves the other hypercube on the screen and ready.

Is it possible to match two hypercubes? What happens? And for three?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you match two hypercubes it will clear the entire board. I think the same thing happens if you match 3, however I'm not positive on that one.

Comment: Seriously? I did not know that (because I never read their page) I've had the opportunity for this several times now ><

Comment: @Noctrine, yep. I haven't had the chance to see it myself, but many people have confirmed that is what happens.

Comment: I did it once and I confirm, the whole board clear...

Comment: Confirmed, yes. This only happens in *blitz* mode. classic mode will just cause the two hypercubes to disappear, leaving other gems untouched.

Answer (score 2):

If you click two hypercubes together when they are side by side, the whole board clears. Unfortunately, when three are in line, all they do is disappear! That stinks!